# Highlight row when cell value is within range

Tags: google-sheets, range, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets with a range from A:I with multiple rows, each having a different value from the other in column "I". I would like to make it so that when the values of column "I" are between `4` - `4.9` then the entire row will be highlighted.

For example, for Row 3, if I3 value is between `4` - `4.9` then A3:I3 will be highlighted.

Additionally, I will be making it so that ranges between `3` - `3.9` will be highlighted a different color, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColmnsA:I and: Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=and($I1>4,$I1<4.9)
```

with one formatting of your choice and then repeat with new values for each different choice of format. You might want some `=`s along with the angle brackets.